# Why right join (A[B]) returns NULL if column is of type list since by default it should return NA?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to know if I have missed something in the documentation or this is a bug and I should post this on GitHub.

```
library(data.table)

dt_list <- data.table(id = c(1, 3),
                 col1 = list(c(1, 2, 3), 2))

dt_2 <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3))

dt_list[dt_2, on = "id"]
#>    id  col1
#> 1:  1 1,2,3
#> 2:  2       # this is NULL
#> 3:  3     2

dt_not_list <- data.table(id = c(1, 3),
                 col1 = c(5, 6))

dt_2 <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3))

dt_not_list[dt_2, on = "id"]
#>    id col1
#> 1:  1    5
#> 2:  2   NA # this is NA
#> 3:  3    6
```

As you can see in the example above - once we have a NULL and once NA. If this is not a bug - how can I get NA in case of list?

NB: I'm afraid that similar problem exists when I make dcast on data.table if column which contains values is of type list, i.e. missing values are filled by NULL instead of NA, but I'm just signaling this on the margin (I still need to double check this) since I'm not sure if this should be a separate question or not.

Comment: The reason is when you subset a list, the missing itm of a list is always NULL. When you subset a vector, the missing value is NA. Just check dt_list$col1[3]; 
dt_not_list$col1[3]

Comment: Thank you. So I see everything is as it should :)